# ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the number of spherical wavefronts I input using Python, this is my code.I'm using Axes3D to plot, but I have a problem, when I plot with "ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=plt.cm.coolwarm(w), shade=False)" doesn´t work and appears me the next message:

`ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.`

My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def spherical_wavefront(n):
    x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, n), np.linspace(-1, 1, n), np.linspace(-1, 1, n))
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    wavefront = np.empty((n, n, n))
    wavefront[r <= 1] = 1/r[r <= 1] * np.exp(1j * r[r <= 1])
    return x, y, z, np.real(wavefront)

num_wavefronts = int(input("How many spherical wavefronts would you like to plot? "))

fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(num_wavefronts):
    x, y, z, w = spherical_wavefront(100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=plt.cm.coolwarm(w), shade=False)
    ax.set_title(f'Spherical Wavefront {i + 1}')
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to obtain, but ax.plot_surface is for plotting surfaces: the z array should have 2 dimensions, and its entries should indicate what is the z-coordinate of the point on the surface with given x- and y-coordinates. In your code the array `z` is 3-dimensional which generates the error. If the goal is to plot a 3-d grid of evenly spaced points whose colors depend on the values of the array w, then you can use ax.scatter with `x`, `y`, `z` giving coordinates of points  and `w` as the color argument.

Comment: How many dimensions does `z` have?

Comment: 1) `plot_surface`  is meant to draw a 2D function, where z is a function of a grid on x and y.  You have something very different.  2) `fig.add_subplot(111,...)` creates a new subplot each time you enter the `for` loop; this will erase the earlier parts.  3) Maybe [matplotlib voxels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/voxels.html) is helpful?